# correct terraform api ip addresses to use in whitelist for azure resource during Terraform Plan

Tags: azure, terraform, ip, firewall, terraform-cloud

When running a Terraform Plan and Apply on cloud (Azure) resources that are firewall protected, how can one find and add the *correct* ip address(es) of the Terraform Cloud Workspace runner to that Azure resource's firewall whitelist? Otherwise, we see errors in the Plan (`403`s) because Terraform Cloud is doing a GET request on the remote cloud resource but doesn't have access.

I ran `curl --request GET https://app.terraform.io/api/meta/ip-ranges | jq '.'`  which returned a series of objects that had ip addresses:

```
{
  "api": [
    ...
  ],
  "notifications": [
    ...
  ],
  "sentinel": [
   ...
  ],
  "vcs": [
   ...
  ]
}
```

Phind suggested to use the ip addresses from the `api` key. I added those to the Azure Firewall whitelist and re-ran the Plan, however, it still came back with the `403` errors. Only when I temporarily opened the Azure resource to all networks does the Terraform Plan succeed without errors and is able to be Applied. This is obviously less than ideal but for now is what I am doing and then I reapply the select ip addresses to the whitelist to the resource in Azure Portal after the Terraform Apply is done.

Comment: To add Terraform Cloud's IP addresses to your Azure resource's firewall, obtain the IP ranges from Terraform Cloud using curl https://app.terraform.io/api/meta/ip-ranges, and then update your Azure resource's firewall settings to include these IPs

Comment: @VinayB what can be tried in your comment that is different from the OP?